# reactjs - axios - request how to improve

Tags: reactjs, react-native, axios, react-hooks, use-state

I have this requests in react state. both of then do pretty much the same purpose. i was thinking about pagination but instead this problem ocorred me. about loading two request separatedly

```js
  // use effect loading hooks api responses
  useEffect(() => {
    const loadNews = async () => {
        try {
            const response = await api.get('science.json');

            const { results } = response.data;
           console.log(results);
           setScience(results);
          } catch (err) {
            // Handle Error Here
            console.error(err);
         }
         };

        loadNews();
     }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    const loadNews = async () => {
        try {
            const response = await api.get('arts.json');

            const { results } = response.data;
           console.log(results);
           setTechnologies(results);
          } catch (err) {
            // Handle Error Here
            console.error(err);
         }
         };

        loadNews();
     }, []);
```

Both are here for the same purpose any solution on not having this code same twice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd be inclined to take the fetching process (getting the results) into its own async function. You'd then set the results in useEffect using that function.

Something like this:

```
async function fetchNews(jsonFile) {
    const response = await api.get(jsonFile);
    const { results } = response.data;
    return results;
}

useEffect(() => {
   fetchNews("science.json")
     .then(res => setScience(res))
     .catch(err => console.error(err))

   fetchNews("arts.json")
     .then(res => setTechnologies(res))
     .catch(err => console.error(err))
}, []);
```

Comment: Thanks for the approach. Should i proceed to create a new file to handle this and the only rendering the data inside a map?

Comment: I mean, should the fetch go to new file?

Comment: You could do both ways I guess, extract these kind of functions as "modules" into separate files, or have them in the same file but preferably outside of your component. Depends on the project and your preference, I think.

Answer (score 2):

This could be

```
useEffect(() => {
  loadNews("arts.json", setScience);
  loadNews("science.json", setTechnologies);
}, []);

const loadNews = async (url, callBack) => {
  try {
    const response = await api.get(url);
    const { results } = response.data;
    console.log(results);
    callBack(results);
  } catch (err) {
    // Handle Error Here
    console.error(err);
  }
}
```

Comment: its pretty much the same. Thank you paveloosha!

Comment: @Lago, you are welcome. I was writing at the same time I guess :)